# How to merge two dataframe base on dates which the datediff is one day?

Tags: pandas

**Input**

```
df1
 
id            A 
2020-01-01    10
2020-02-07    20
2020-04-09    30

df2
id           B
2019-12-31   50
2020-02-06   20
2020-02-07   70
2020-04-08   34
2020-04-09   44
```

**Goal**

```
df
id            A     B
2020-01-01    10   50
2020-02-07    20   20
2020-04-09    30   34
```

The detail as follows:

- df1 merges df2 base on id, which add columns from df2.
- the type of id is datetime.
- merge rules: df1 based on yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply add 1 day to df2's ID column before merging?

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(id=df2['id'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)), on='id')

          id   A   B
0 2020-01-01  10  50
1 2020-02-07  20  20
2 2020-04-09  30  34
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.merge_asof`

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='id',tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1 day'),allow_exact_matches=False)
          id   A   B
0 2020-01-01  10  50
1 2020-02-07  20  20
2 2020-04-09  30  34
```

Comment: This is almost correct, the outputs for B are wrong. The problem is if asof finds the same date in df2 as df1 it'd use that instead of yesterday's date.

Comment: @cs95 notice , just add the allow_exact_matches :-)

Comment: OK nice, this taught me something new. PS; `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='id', direction='backward', allow_exact_matches=False)` also works and is probably more correct since it only looks in the backward direction (instead of generally as a tolerance value).